# Removing a package from composer's lockfile before install

Tags: composer-php

Is it possible to remove a package and it's dependencies from composer's lockfile before install?

Things I've tried that don't work:

```
composer remove package --no-update # Only updates composer.json
composer remove package # Removes only this package, installs all its dependancies
```

Comment: What possible reason could you have to do this? The whole point of the `composer.lock` file is to precisely reproduce environments.

Comment: CI testing on old versions of PHP that don't support the require-dev, which also contains phpunit. Unless there's a second require-dev hiding somewhere

Comment: What is an "old version of PHP that doesn't support `require-dev`"? Isn't `require-dev` purely a Composer thing? And what do you mean by "a second `require-dev` hiding somewhere"?

Comment: I mean I have things in `require-dev` that are required for development (As the name suggests) but that won't work in PHP versions the project is supposed to support in production. Most notably `php-cs-fixer`

Comment: So the problem is that you want to install some things from `require-dev` (like PHPUnit) so you can run tests even against old versions of PHP, but other things in `require-dev` (like `php-cs-fixer`) cannot be installed with those old versions of PHP, thus preventing `composer install` from completing properly?

Comment: Exactly! I'd have hoped removing `php-cs-fixer` would do the trick but it doesn't remove its dependencies and those are the ones conflicting.